# Not printing second column of csv file c++

Tags: c++, parsing

```
std::ifstream file_stream1(outfile,std::ifstream::out | std::ifstream::binary);
    std::vector<double> file;
     std::vector<double> file1;
    std :: string line;
    while (getline (file_stream1, line))
    {

        double item[100];
        std :: string dataEntry; //a particular entry as a string

        std :: istringstream lineStream(line);

        for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            //get one entry
            getline( lineStream, dataEntry, ',');
            lineStream >> std::ws; //remove whitespace after the comma and before the next entry

            std:: istringstream( dataEntry ) >> item[i];
            std :: cout << item[i] << std ::endl ;
            file.push_back (item[i]);
            file1.push_back (item[i]);

        }
```

1. I am trying to read a csv file c++, I have two columns of all double data but the problem is it is printing only first column ?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop has only one iteration, use:

for(int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)